# A Rhyming Riley, again with feeling

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Prefix: A place for you to sleep, the twin cancelled his reservation,

Infix:  To give some strings a sweep, and add to the jubilation,

Suffix: Your opinion, just a peep, less a common URL cessation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> instrument

Prefix: A place for you to sleep, the twin cancelled his reservation,

> inn; one of the 'twin' letters is absent

Infix: To give some strings a sweep, and add to the jubilation,

> strum; to sweep across the strings of an instrument, producing a chord

Suffix: Your opinion, just a peep, less a common URL cessation

> comment; take away the 'com'